Junit 5's @Testcontainers doesn't work with cucumber and spring boot 3
I wrote some cucumber test and noticed that @Testcontainers don't work when used with cucumber. If I run my cucumber tests like this:
import io.cucumber.spring.CucumberContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.testcontainers.service.connection.ServiceConnection;
import org.testcontainers.containers.KafkaContainer;
import org.testcontainers.containers.OracleContainer;
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Container;
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Testcontainers;
import org.testcontainers.utility.DockerImageName;

@Testcontainers
@CucumberContextConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
//@ActiveProfiles("h2")
public class CucumberSpringConfiguration {
    @Container
    @ServiceConnection
    static OracleContainer oracleContainer = new OracleContainer("gvenzl/oracle-xe:21-slim-faststart");

    @Container
    @ServiceConnection
    static KafkaContainer kafkaContainer = new KafkaContainer(DockerImageName.parse("confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.2.1"));
}

The spring application will fail with:
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception with message: Mapped port can only be obtained after the container is started
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:177)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:644)
    ... 76 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mapped port can only be obtained after the container is started
    at org.testcontainers.shaded.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:512)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerState.getMappedPort(ContainerState.java:161)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.OracleContainer.getOraclePort(OracleContainer.java:194)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.OracleContainer.getJdbcUrl(OracleContainer.java:120)
    at org.springframework.boot.testcontainers.service.connection.jdbc.JdbcContainerConnectionDetailsFactory$JdbcContainerConnectionDetails.getJdbcUrl(JdbcContainerConnectionDetailsFactory.java:65)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration.createDataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:56)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.dataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:117)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:140)
    ... 77 more

This is because the containers were not started so @Testcontainers doesn't seem to do anything. I also noticed that if I put in this class @BeforeAll/ @AfterAll from junit package, they are not being invoked at all so junit integration seems pretty dead to me.
Now, if I manually start the containers in cucumber's @BeforeAll/ @AfterAll, my containers will be started and everything will work:
import io.cucumber.java.AfterAll;
import io.cucumber.java.BeforeAll;
import io.cucumber.spring.CucumberContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.testcontainers.service.connection.ServiceConnection;
import org.testcontainers.containers.KafkaContainer;
import org.testcontainers.containers.OracleContainer;
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Container;
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Testcontainers;
import org.testcontainers.utility.DockerImageName;

@Testcontainers
@CucumberContextConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
//@ActiveProfiles("h2")
public class CucumberSpringConfiguration {
    @Container
    @ServiceConnection
    static OracleContainer oracleContainer = new OracleContainer("gvenzl/oracle-xe:21-slim-faststart");

    @Container
    @ServiceConnection
    static KafkaContainer kafkaContainer = new KafkaContainer(DockerImageName.parse("confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.2.1"));

    @BeforeAll
    public static void setUp() {
        System.out.println("++++++++ BEFORE ALL ++++++++");

        oracleContainer
                .withReuse(true)
                .start();

        kafkaContainer
                .withReuse(true)
                .start();
    }

    @AfterAll
    public static void tearDown() {
        System.out.println("++++++++ AFTER ALL ++++++++");

        oracleContainer.stop();
        kafkaContainer.stop();
    }
}

Notice that I am using BeforeAll/ AfterAll from cucumber package and not junit.
In all the tutorials that I have seen on the internet, @Testcontainer seems to work fine with cucumber.
I am using spring boot 3.3.0 and the following junit/ cucumber deps:
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-bom</artifactId>
            <version>7.18.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-bom</artifactId>
            <version>5.10.2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-suite</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-testcontainers</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
        <artifactId>oracle-xe</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.8</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.8</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.8</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

The cucumber config class looks like:
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.ConfigurationParameter;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.IncludeEngines;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SelectClasspathResource;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.Suite;

import static io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.Constants.GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME;


@Suite
@IncludeEngines("cucumber")
@SelectClasspathResource("features")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "com.example.cucumber")
public class CucumberRunnerTest {
}

What could be the problem?

You're spot on! The container is not starting because @TestContainers and @Container annotations both belong to junit-jupiter-engine. Cucumber uses junit-platform-suite-engine (here is the list of JUnit 5 test engines).
I managed to make it work by removing both annotations that are useless and starting the container programmatically, just like you did.
However, you still can count on the Spring Boot 3 @ServiceConnection annotation to automatically set up the connection pool for you.
N.B. for readers:

@BeforeAll and @AfterAll come from io.cucumber.java (as already mentioned)
I don't have the issue of .withReuse(true) allowing multiple applications use the same container because I run the tests in a pipeline where each step runs in its own container.

Here's how my configuration classes look like:
import io.cucumber.java.BeforeAll;
import io.cucumber.spring.CucumberContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.testcontainers.service.connection.ServiceConnection;
import org.testcontainers.containers.PostgreSQLContainer;

@CucumberContextConfiguration
@SpringBootTest
public class CucumberSpringConfiguration {

    @ServiceConnection
    static final PostgreSQLContainer<?> postgreSQLContainer =
            new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:16.2");

    @BeforeAll
    public static void setup() {
        postgreSQLContainer.withReuse(true).start();
    }

    @AfterAll
    public static void tearDown() {
        postgreSQLContainer.stop();
    }
}


and
import static io.cucumber.core.options.Constants.FILTER_TAGS_PROPERTY_NAME;
import static io.cucumber.core.options.Constants.PLUGIN_PROPERTY_NAME;

import org.junit.platform.suite.api.ConfigurationParameter;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SelectClasspathResource;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SelectPackages;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.Suite;

@Suite
@SelectClasspathResource("features")
@SelectPackages({"package-with-step-definitions"})
@ConfigurationParameter(
        key = PLUGIN_PROPERTY_NAME,
        value =
                "pretty,\n"
                        + "html:target/AcceptanceTestReports/report.html,\n" //
                        + "json:target/AcceptanceTestReports/report.json,\n" //
                        + "junit:target/AcceptanceTestReports/report.xml")


Cucumber doesn't actually use the Suite Engine. However if you want to use Cucumber with JUnit and Maven or Gradle you have to use the Suite Engine because Maven and Gradle don't have anyway to select tests that aren't in a class file. It's a workaround.

The @SelectPackages annotation doesn't do anything for you. It selects feature files in a package in which you don't have any.

this worked for me as well after changing @BeforeAll and @AfterAll from junit to cucumber

@Testcontainers are a JUnit Jupiter extension

1.1. What is JUnit 5?
Unlike previous versions of JUnit, JUnit 5 is composed of several different modules from three different sub-projects.
JUnit 5 = JUnit Platform + JUnit Jupiter + JUnit Vintage

JUnit Jupiter and JUnit Vintage are test engines on the JUnit Platform. Just as the JUnit Suite (that runs the @Suite annotation) and also Cucumber. This generally speaking means that features that are part of Jupiter, will not work work for any of the other test engines.
For example when looking at the source code of org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Testcontainers:
package org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
...
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@ExtendWith(TestcontainersExtension.class)
@Inherited
public @interface Testcontainers {
...

You can see that TestContainers is meta annotated with @ExtendWith(TestcontainersExtension.class) which makes it a Jupiter extension.
@TestContainers in combination with Spring are slow
When using @TestContainers a new test container is created for each test method. This is slow. Additionally, when using Spring Boot, this also means the application context has to be restarted. This makes things even slower.
Ideally you reuse the application context and test container for all tests. This can be done by starting the test container through a ContextCustomizerFactory, and by ensuring the test data you create is unique.
Note: while you can use .withReuse(true) to reuse the test container, this means the container is not scoped to a specific application context. As a result the details of one application context (from a completely different project) can leak into another one.
